# Load panel inside panel

Tags: java, swing, panel

I have one main frame and inside this frame I'm showing other panels.
But one of panels contain button which purpose is to show another panel - something like show panel inside panel.

This is code of panel from which I want load another panel:

```
public class PnlConnectionType extends JPanel {

private JPanel cardPanel;
private CardLayout cl;

/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public PnlConnectionType() {

    cardPanel = new JPanel();
    cardPanel.setBounds(new Rectangle(10, 11, 775, 445));

    cl = new CardLayout();
    cardPanel.setLayout(cl);

    setBounds(new Rectangle(10, 11, 774, 465));
    setLayout(null);

    JButton btnRS485 = new JButton("CONNECTION BY RS485");
    btnRS485.setBounds(20, 23, 266, 107);
    add(btnRS485);

    JButton btnNoConnectionoffline = new JButton("NO CONNECTION (OFFLINE)");
    btnNoConnectionoffline.setBounds(20, 159, 266, 107);
    add(btnNoConnectionoffline);

    final settingsPanel2 settPnl2 = new settingsPanel2();
    settPnl2.setBounds(new Rectangle(10, 11, 774, 465));
    settPnl2.setSize(775,465);
    settPnl2.setBounds(10, 11, 775, 445);

    cardPanel.add(settPnl2, "1");

    btnRS485.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cl.show(cardPanel, "1");                
        }
    });           
}   
}
```

When I click on button panel is not showed. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are using null layout which is trouble for many reasons. Have a look at [how to use layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).